# Play Json Recursive Reads

Tags: json, scala, recursion, playframework

I'm working on consuming an API which exposes an object at multiple layers within it's response. For example for some responses we get back a:

```
{ 
  "error": { 
    "code": "123", 
    "description": "Description" 
  } 
}
```

But in other situations it response with:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message_id": "123",
      "error": {
        "code": "123",
        "description": "Description"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In both cases the error object is identical and in both case I don't actually care about the rest of the payload. I was hoping to use the \\ recursive JsPath operator, however the implementation below fails:

```
case class ErrorMessage(code: String, description: String)
implicit val errorMessageFormat = Json.format[ErrorMessage]

case class ErrorResponse(errors: Seq[ErrorMessage])
implicit val errorResponseFormat: Format[ErrorResponse] = Format(
  (__ \\ "error").read[Seq[ErrorMessage]].map(ErrorResponse),
  (__ \ "errors").write[Seq[ErrorMessage]].contramap((r: ErrorResponse) => r.errors)
)
```

This gives an error:

```
JsError(List((//error,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray())))))
```

I understand why: The `(__ \\ "error")` returns a `Seq[JsValue]`, where as my read call is expecting a `JsArray`.

Is there a nice way a round this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read `error` as an array, but per you example, it's an object.

Comment: @healsjnr you have posted invalid json this is the link to see json data http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: @pedrofurla yeah, that's what I was trying to solve. I was hoping I'd be able to convert the `Seq[JsValue]` to a `JsArray` by doing `(JsArray(__ \\ "error")).read[...]` but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first piece is already a Seq, just map the internal elements as you would map single objects. I'm not very familiar with the framework (I use Json4s myself mostly), but by your description sounds like

```
ErrorResponse((__ \\ "error").map(_.read[Seq[ErrorMessage]]))
```

Should be closer to what you want.`(__ \\ "error")` gives you a `Seq` of `JsValues`, `map` does something for every `JsValue`, `read` converts a single `JsValue` to an `ErrorMessage` and the resulting `Seq[ErrorMessage]` you pass to the `ErrorResponse` constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately the types don't quite line up for this with Play Json. In Particular `(__ \\ "error")` is actually a JsPath in this context. It's not evaluated in to a Seq[JsValue] until it's passed to the `Reads.read` method.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone trying to do something similar, the below works.

```
val errorResponseReads = Reads[ErrorResponse] { value: JsValue =>
  val errorsJsArray: JsArray = JsArray(value \\ "error")
  errorsJsArray.validate[Seq[ErrorMessage]].map(ErrorResponse)
}
```

The format then becomes:

```
implicit val errorResponseFormat: Format[ErrorResponse] = Format(
  errorResponseReads,
  (__ \ "errors").write[Seq[ErrorMessage]].contramap((r: ErrorResponse) => r.errors)
)
```

Basically you need to define Reads that you use explicitly. In the reads you can then use the recursive search to return a `Seq[JsValue]` and then create a `JsArray` that can be validated as normal.

This works fine, it would be nice if we didn't have to define a separate Reads[T] though.